# Casting Return Value for JDBCTemplate.QueryForObject

Tags: java, casting

I find this form of the query very convenient for returning a single value/single row from a database call, and I am fine with it throwing an exception if there is something wrong.  But I have it in my head that doing a cast is generally a bad practice.

Is the cast here frowned upon?

```
String name = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
        sql, new Object[] { custId }, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring 3.1, the [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) can use generics and varargs with [queryForObject](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String name = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, String.class, custId);
```

Prior to Spring 3.1, this was available through getSimpleJdbcTemplate()

```
String name = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, String.class, custId);
```

EDIT:

This requires JDK 1.5 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to cast if you're using a recent version of Spring, since it's a generic method and the [signature of the method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) is now:

```
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType) throws DataAccessException
```

If you're using an old version, then either cast, or upgrade to a recent version.